# Extending the objects from Parent class to child class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two classes in which the student extends from Person via inheritance. I can call the walk () method of parent from the child class. Is there any way I can call the run method in same fashion which is inside an object for both the classes, Since I’m new to JavaScript let know if I’m making mistake?

```
//Parent Class

class Person {
  athlete = {
    name: "ronald",
    age: 27,
    run: function () {
      console.log("parent cal")
    }
  }
  walk() {
    console.log('parent call');
  }
}

//Child Class
class Student extends Person {
  athlete = {
    name: "ronald",
    age: 27,
    run: function () {
      //is there any way i can call the run method present in person class ??
    }
  }

  walk() {
    super.walk();// this would call the method present in person 
  }
}
```

Comment: `athlete` is part of an instance, IOW: does not exist unless your create an instance of `Person`,  so it's not possible to call something that does not exist yet.

Comment: `athlete` is more or less just an object, so you should create a separate class for it (e.g. `Athlete`). If you want, you can then create another class called something like `StudentAthlete`, which extends the `Athlete` class. The `run` method can then use `super.run()`.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson instead of creating another class is there any other way to call the method present in an object ??

Comment: it seems you are missing the point. You cannot call a function defined inside a class unless it's a static method (a static method is defined as such and can't deal with object properties because there's no object to deal with). Once you have an object (that should be create as let object = new Class();) you can call the function defined in the class the object was instantiated from: object.function(). What kind of invocation do you expect to do? on which object? to which method?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I want to  call the run method present in person class from the student class run method

Comment: doesn't your code already works like that? if you do: `let o = new Student(); o.walk();` it will indeed log on console "parent call" as expected because the call on o.walk() will linvoke the function in the base class that logs that string on console. I still don't get what's wrong. Sorry I got it now.. I'm going to rephrase soon...

Comment: people before me suggested already what I'm going to tell you now.. it took longer for me to get it. By the way you could refactor those class in several ways adding a contructor or getters but the point is that's not the way to deal with inheritance. Your Person class (and Student also) holds a value for the athlet property like it was a static property and you want to access to that object from an object instantiated by the child class. There are ways to achieve that but it will be messed up because it won't work as you expect. I'm afraid I can't help you further here

Answer (score 1):

Well, my approach here may seem a bit different from what you have already done but I think it can be more concise and explanatory for being able to do efficient code maintenance in a future.

First of all, I created a `class Person_params` for declaring all properties which I will pass directly to my `Person Class`.

After this I also declared `self = this;` at the beginning of my `Class Person` which actually acquires all object properties and saves them to the `self`.

By using `self`, you can refer to the global scope in a way that will work not only in a window context (self will resolve to window.self) but also in a worker context (self will then resolve to WorkerGlobalScope.self). This part is from the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self

At the end, when I call `console.log('${self.name} hides!');` at my `Student Class`, it actually inherits the properties of `Person Class` which I passed with the `Person_params` Class. In this case `Person_params` is basically used as a Class which serves as a `constructor` for the `Person Class`.

```js
//Params for Person Class
class Person_params {
    //constructor params to pass to the Person class
    constructor() {
        this.name;
        this.age;
   }
}

class Person {
  self = this;
  constructor(Person_params) {
     self.name = Person_params.name;
     self.age= Person_params.age;
     this.run();
  }
  
  walk() {
    console.log(`${self.name} walks!`);
  }
  
  run() {
      console.log(`${self.name} runs!`);
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  // self inherits from its parent class
  hide() {
    console.log(`${self.name} hides!`);
  }
}


let personParams = new Person_params();
personParams.name = "Raul";
personParams.age = 27;

let person = new Person(personParams);
let student = new Student(personParams);

student.walk();
student.hide();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for finding time and replying to my question, but the structure which I have is totally different from the solution you have given .run method is present the object athlete, that's where I'm stuck up.